# Passing a specific instance of an object in a constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I have created a Location class that contains the city and state fields. I then created a Hotel class that contains the other address fields and telephone number. The end goal is to be able to add multiple hotels to a single location. I want to pass the location instances I have created through the hotel constructor, What is the best way to go about doing this?

```
package reservations;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] Args){

        addLocations();
        addHotels();
        ReservationDisplay check = ReservationDisplay.getInstance();
        check.getUserInfo();

    }

    public static void addLocations(){
        Location dc = new Location("Washington", "DC");
        Location cali = new Location("San Francisco", "CA");
        Location ny = new Location("Ney York", "NY");
        Location vegas = new Location("Las Vegas", "NV");
        Location miami = new Location("Miami", "FL");
    }

    public static void addHotels(){

        Hotel mgm = new Hotel("Blah", "1234 Blvd", "55555", "(999)-999-9999", vegas);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the design.  Two different hotels most likely would not be at the same _exact_ address.  If you were modelling your database table, you probably would not keep a separate table for the addresses.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It looks like a `Location` is actually a misnomer for a `City` since it only holds a City/State. 2 hotels in the same city is logical. The name of the Location class is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a constructor in the Hotel class that takes in a Location.

Something like this

```
public Hotel(Location l, <other fields>)
{
    // Set other fields
    this.location = l;
    l.addHotel(this);
}
```

This assumes that there is a field in the hotel class to hold it's location and a `addHotel(Hotel h)` method in the Location class to hold of a location's hotels.

Then when you're creating your hotels you would call them like this::

```
Hotel h = new Hotel(ny, <otherfields>);
```

You would need to have a reference to the locations you've created when creating your hotels.

EDIT:

To make the locations you create in `addLocations()` visible outside of the function you need to make them field variables (either directly or create a list/map to store all of them)

Something like this would make since:

```
public class Test {
   private static Map<String, Location> locations = new HashMap<String, Location>();
   // Or list or straight variables or other way of holding the locations
   // Some structure to hold the hotels will be necessary too


   public static void addLocations()
   {
      locations.put("Washington", new Location("Washington", "DC"));
      // Same line for other locations
   }


   public static void addHotels()
   {
      Hotel h = new Hotel(locations.get("Washington"), <other fields>);
      // Add the hotel to the list/map whatever of hotels to use it elsewhere
   }
```

Comment: This is basically what I tried but its telling me that "vegas cannot be resolved to a variable". I'm pretty sure it's because I declared vegas in the addLocations block and the variable is out of scope but I don't know how to get around that.

Comment: @oznomal Sounds reasonable. What you need is to make the locations visible outside of the location addLocations method. I'll edit my answer to show that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are doing in your example seems alright. If you were to model it in a db you would keep only the zip code in the hotel table and then have another table mapping zip codes to city names. 
I would say doing it your way is an okay way to map this into your objects.